# Subdomain with different ip on same server

Tags: ip, vps, subdomain

I am creating a subdomain with a different account (same name-servers)

But I am wondering if there are any advantages to giving the subdomain a dedicated ip (same server hosting)

Comment: Different IP like 192.168.77.5 and 172.27.9.9?

Comment: Yes different dedicated ip, does it make any difference?

Comment: Only if you need to use different SSL certificates.

Comment: Ok so that is a bad thing, having to use different certificates. Is there any performance difference in terms of networking? (All requests coming on one ip vs two)

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes it possible to have services available only on the sub-domain or only on the domain, or to have different behavior depending on the IP address.

As noted in the comments, you can have different SSL certificates. But given that the both belong to the same domain hierarchy, a single certificate with an alias would work just as well.

Network overhead will be minimal.  However, originating traffic from both IP addresses is not a trivial task.  By default all outgoing connections will originate from one IP address.

I generally limit use of extra IP addresses to test environments where each IP address can have different software listing on a port.  In a small production environment, it might be appropriate to have a publicly facing test server on a second IP address.  Other than that I haven't encountered a good use case for a second public IP address.

Comment: I know it can be done. But why do it?

Comment: @PrivatMamtora Either of the first two paragraphs would be reasons to add a second IP address for the sub-domain.  I clarified the first case. If neither applies, I can't think of a reason to add the second IP address.

Comment: Second paragraph is a work around if it was implemented. I am planning to provide a service on a subdomain. But you can still put the domain and the sub domain on the same IP. Why would you separate it? What is the advantage? If outgoing connections originate from one IP then multiple ips on one vps is not useful.

Comment: Ah you said by default, if you manage to return on different ip, there will still be a bottle neck on disk I/O.

Comment: @PrivatMamtora I've updated my answer to provide a possible use.  Adding additional IPs won't resolve an I/O bottleneck, but isn't likely to cause one either.